# How do I convert Swift date and TimeInterval so that I can send to php server?

Tags: php, swift, nsdate, alamofire

I have a swift date and timeInterval that I want to send to php server via Alamofire. What should I do to these variables in order to send either via JSON or param?

Is there a specific format I should use?

( I do not know how the interaction between those two work)

Comment: Can you specify what your php server accepts? You can convert your Swift date and time interval in UTC format and then send it to your server.

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to make it more specific/clear (see [help me is not a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: A **server** defines services. The service defines what input it takes. Nobody but the person understanding that server can answer your question. How are we supposed to know what kind of data **your** server is expecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to save your db with php or etc. , you can use `datetime` format. You can send string to db ' also It recognize the string and save as date format to db. Your format can be "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"

Answer (score 1):

There are plethora of choices of Date format conversion you can use.

My favorite is [RFC 3339](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3339.txt) because it creates least possible confusion among date formats and it is completely suitable for [PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php#datetime.constants.rfc3339) as well.

```
extension Date {
    init?(rfc3339String: String) {
        self.init()

        let localeId = "en_US_POSIX"
        let rfc3339DateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ"
        let fmt = DateFormatter()
        fmt.locale = Locale(identifier: localeId)
        fmt.dateFormat = rfc3339DateFormat
        fmt.timeZone = TimeZone.current
        self = fmt.date(from: rfc3339String)!
    }

    func rfc3339String() -> String {
        let localeId = "en_US_POSIX"
        let rfc3339DateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ"
        let fmt = DateFormatter()
        fmt.locale = Locale(identifier: localeId)
        fmt.dateFormat = rfc3339DateFormat
        fmt.timeZone = TimeZone.current
        return fmt.string(from: self)
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is: it is up to that server to define what it expects. Nobody but the OP himself has the means to understand what *his* server is expecting.

Comment: @GhostCat, as far as i understood, OP is about to implement both: front-end and back-end parts. But your comment is reasonable.